# How to set axis range R

Tags: r, axis

I'm having trouble setting my axis range in r. My data only has values from 2 to 9 on the x axis but I want it to go from 1 to 10. Any quick tips please?

```
head(SS)
  Phase Bed Site ACC X.M.SA
1     1   1    1  NG     NO
2     1   1    2  NG     NO
3     1   1    3  SG     NO
4     1   1    4  SG     NO
5     1   1    5  SG     NO
6     1   2    1  SG     NO

XMSA<-factor(SS$X.M.SA)
ACC<-factor(SS$ACC,ordered = TRUE,levels=c("NG","SG","LG","MG","HG"))

boxplot(ACC[XMSA=="MSSA"]~SS$Bed[XMSA=="MSSA"],
xlab="Bed",ylab="Growth",
las=1, yaxt="n",ylim=c(1,5),xlim=c(1,10))
axis(2, at=c(1,2,3,4,5),labels=c("NG","SG","LG","MG","HG"),las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your x is not a factor? Can you post the first few lines of your data frame?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without data, I tried to reproduce your plot error:

```
plot(x=as.factor(2:8),y=2:8,xlim = c(1,10))
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

Changing your plot to:

```
boxplot(x= as.numeric(as.character(SS$Bed[XMSA=="MSSA"])),
y= ACC[XMSA=="MSSA"]
xlab="Bed",ylab="Growth",
las=1, yaxt="n",ylim=c(1,5),xlim=c(1,10))
axis(2, at=c(1,2,3,4,5),labels=c("NG","SG","LG","MG","HG"),las=1)
```

Might solve your problem.

### Edit

It seems that the formula changes to factors and orders it from 1 to the number of items, so I'll use your trick on the y axis to solve this.

```
boxplot(ACC[XMSA=="MSSA"]~SS$Bed[XMSA=="MSSA"],
xlab="Bed",ylab="Growth",
las=1, yaxt="n",ylim=c(1,5),xlim=c(0,9),xaxt="n")
axis(2, at=1:5,labels=c("NG","SG","LG","MG","HG"),las=1)
axis(1, at=0:9,labels=1:10,las=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Bed is categorical ordinal. ACC is a factor. XMSA is categorical numerical. Your code produces one boxplot for me not for each bed...

Comment: I edited my comment, new version may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Could you clarify why this isn't so straight forward as it might be?

Comment: I did not check this, but in my opinion, either Bed is stored as a factor or it is coerced to a factor when using the formula. So it will order from 1 to 8 in the same as is it would disply text for example. You wanted to add 1 tick before and 1 after, so I forced the xlim to be 0 to 9, and changed the labels to be 1 to 10 to display as you wanted.